# Unable to update the fields from edit form using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, actioncontroller

In my Index view, for edit button I have the below code:

```
<td id="EditButton"><%= link_to "Edit", edit_comment_path(data.Metric+","+data.HouseId+","+data.ADate.to_s) %></td>
```

In my Comment controller, I have the following code for edit and update:

```
def edit
            edit_array=params[:id].split(',')
            @one = edit_array[0]
            @two = edit_array[1]
            @three = edit_array[2]
            @comment = Comment.find_by(Metric: @one , HouseId: @two , ADate: @three)      
end
       def update
            @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
            if @comment.update(comments_params)
              redirect_to metrics_path
            else
              render 'edit'
            end   
    end
```

I have this form tag in my edit form:

```
<%= form_for :comments_controller, url: comments_path(@comment) do |f| %>
```

Fields in edit form:

```
<tr>
          <td><%= @comment.Metric %></td>
          <td><%= @comment.HouseId%></td>
          <td><%= @comment.ADate%></td>
          <td><%= f.select :IsAlarmCreated, options_for_select([["True", "1"], ["False", "0"]]), :class => 'chosen-select', :required => true, selected: @comment.IsAlarmCreated  %></td>
          <td><%= f.text_field :UserName, value: @remote_user %></td>
          <td><%= f.text_field :Comments, value: @comment.Comments, required: true  %></td>
          <td><%= f.submit "Save"%></td>
```

I am performing the following actions:
Index page gets loaded
Upon click on edit, it navigates to edit page
I will make some changes to fields and click on save
Now, it is being redirected to comments with the below error:

> The action 'create' could not be found for CommentsController

Expecting to redirect to Index view of Metric controller after updating the values in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You use a wrong path for the form, use `comment_path(@comment)` (singular). `comments_path(@comment)` results in `/comments.123` instead of `/comments/123`

It's also possible that `@comment` found in `#edit` method is a `nil` and form is submitted to `/comments` path.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

Comment: Using singular form (comment_path(@comment)) is giving me the error:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Added these two for validating:
`puts @comment
puts @comment.class`

which results in 

`#<Comment:0x00007fbf7d1364d0>
Comment`

Comment: It  means  that `@comment` is `nil` (as I said ins the second part of the answer) and you need to fix the way you fetch it. I'd suggest using plain old integer id instead of this complex date/metric structure

Comment: Where have you put it? Check also `@comment.id`